# Git add to stage individual lines - like --patch but more precise?

Tags: git, git-add

Sometimes the hunks offered to you when you run git add --patch include unrelated changes mixed up with each other because the lines are physically close to each other in the file.

Is there a way to interactively add changes to the staging area on a line-by-line basis?

Comment: `git add -p` lets you drill down to individual changes, but if you have adjacent lines with unrelated changes, it won't split them. Maybe look at the Darcs porcelain? I liked how Darcs does these things but have not actually explored this option myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can type <kbd>e</kbd> (for 'edit') when you are adding a specific patch with mixed content (too mixed for <kbd>s</kbd> or 'split' to work).

That allows you to delete the lines you don't want to add.

Then you can test what you have added with a `git stash --keep-index`, in order to see if that is working.